# fetching selected radio buttons having value in database in online examination website(php)

Tags: php

I am making an online examination website,I need to fetch selected value of radio buttons to compute final result to show it to the user , i coded as:

```
<form method="POST" action="result1.php">

<div style="height:900px;width:1200px;color: black;margin-left:25px;">
<?php
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="online_exams";
$conn=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);
$x=$_REQUEST['c1'];
$result=mysql_query("select q.qno,q.ques,a.a1,a.a2,a.a3,a.a4 from ques q,ans a where a.cid=q.cid and a.cid=$x and a.qno=q.qno",$conn);
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows>0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo $row['qno'];
 echo"<br>";
echo $row['ques']; echo "<br/>";
?>

<input type="radio"  name="'<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>'"value="'<?php echo $row['a1']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['a1'];  echo "<br/>"; ?>
<input type="radio" name="'<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>'" value="'<?php echo $row['a2']; ?>'" ><?php echo  $row['a2']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio" name="'<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>'" value="'<?php e  cho $row['a3']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['a3']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio"  name="'<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>'"value="'<?php   echo $row['a4']; ?>'" ><?php echo $row['a4']; echo "<br/>";?> 

<?php

  }}}

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
```

and then in the other page to compute result ,while fetching values desired result is not obtained,since the values of radiobuttons are stored in the database ,i could not get any oyher way how to retrieve them ,following is the other code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="online_exams";
$conn=mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn);

$result=mysql_query("select q.qno,q.cans,q.ques,a.a1,a.a2,a.a3,a.a4 from ques q,ans a where a.cid=q.cid and a.qno=q.qno",

$conn);


$x = 0;
$score = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if(isset($_POST['$row['qno']']))
$answered = $_POST[' $row['qno']'];
$correct = $row['cans'] ;

if ($answered == $correct ) {
    $score++;
}


$x = $x + 1;
}
echo 'You had a total of ' . $score . ' out of ' . $x . ' questions right!';
```

}
    ?>

Comment: What is `$row['qno']` ?

Comment: $row['qno'] is the question number fetched from the table

Comment: Ok try with `$_POST[$row['qno']`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="radio"  name="<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['a1']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['a1'];  echo "<br/>"; ?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['a2']; ?>" ><?php echo  $row['a2']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>" value="<?php e  cho $row['a3']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['a3']; echo "<br/>";?>
<input type="radio"  name="<?php echo $row['qno']; ?>" value="<?php   echo $row['a4']; ?>" ><?php echo $row['a4']; echo "<br/>";?>
```

I think having single quotation after/before " was messing it up. Same with values. Since you are not echoing the entire line, no need to have a quotation to separate constants from variables.

Basically you had value="'1'" instead of value="1"

Comment: these solutions are not giving output 
There is an error stating-
 
syntax error unexpected 'qno'(T_STRING),expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\online examination system \php\result1.php on line 25

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error, change here, also use brackets even when you write code of one or two line, its good practice

```
  if(isset($_POST[$row['qno']])){
      $answered = $_POST[$row['qno']];
  }
```